# Clicking Bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler makes animated content wider than screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a website utilising Bootstrap's resume theme ([demo here](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/resume/)), but after adding my content and custom styling, I'm experiencing a problem in mobile viewports. For some reason, every time I press the navbar-toggler icon, the website width widens past the viewport, making the menu and all content slightly wider and offscreen, demanding the user to scroll horizontally. It's incredibly frustrating, since the problem only arises after clicking the toggler, if you just scroll down the site, it stays within viewport perfectly as intended.

Here is a demo of the problem:

[image]

Code is available on Github: https://github.com/anzuj/florian:

- [HTML](https://github.com/anzuj/florian/blob/master/index.html)
- [Modified CSS](https://github.com/anzuj/florian/blob/master/css/resume.min.css)

I've narrowed the problem down to the animated cogs on the background:

```
<div class="gear-bg">
      <i id="gear1" class="fas fa-cog  spin"></i>
      <i id="gear2" class="fas fa-cog  spin-back"></i>
      <i id="gear3" class="fas fa-cog spin"></i>
      <i id="gear4" class="fas fa-cog spin-back"></i>
    </div>
```

They are styled in CSS sheet as such:

```
.gear-bg {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gear1,
#gear2,
#gear3,
#gear4 {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
}

#gear1 {
    color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.096);
    z-index: -1;
    top: 65px;
    font-size: 300px;
    right: 395px;
}

#gear2 {
    color: rgba(231, 151, 86, 0.137);
    z-index: -1;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 400px;
}

#gear3 {
    color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.212);
    z-index: -1;
    top: 365px;
    right: 340px;
    font-size: 180px;
}

#gear4 {
    color: rgba(240, 142, 86, 0.212);
    z-index: -1;
    right: 50px;
    font-size: 240px;
    top: 450px;
}

.spin {
    -webkit-animation: spin 90s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 90s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 90s linear infinite;
}

.spin-back {
    -webkit-animation: spin-back 100s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin-back 100s linear infinite;
    animation: spin-back 100s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin-back {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin-back {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin-back {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't max-width and overflow hiding on the parent div solve the problem? If possible, I would really love to keep the elements, since they add a nice thematic touch.

It's definitely a bit of a handful to chew, but perhaps a seasoned eye would know which troublesome attributes to search for.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, since this site is part of my portfolio attempting to secure a junior position and the fact I'm no closer to understanding why my gears affect the toggler this way is a bit disheartening.

Thank you for anyone caring to read and think along!

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example please in snippet or code-pen

Comment: this problem created from another section that bigger than wide or not provide margin, please first be sure the other sections proper margin and width .

Comment: The problem you're describing does not happen on the theme website. Your expectation that someone will clone and build your project from github is unrealistic. Create a [mcve] inside your question (using the snippet tool) if you need help.

Comment: Thank you and apologies. I tried replicating the theme in codepen, but the gears did not appear there at all. In any case, I found the solution meanwhile, posted it below :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution with a help of a fellow coder! This did the trick: I added this to the `.gear-bg` parent element and removed `max-width: 100%` from it:

```
position: fixed;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm a bit late didn't see that you already figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by given those animated cogs `position absolute` without given their parent any positions.

So just add this to `gear-bg`:

```css
.gear-bg {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**Note** that `z-index` is needed to set the cogs behind your content not overlap it. You'll see that if you increased their opacity.

[image]

Also, there are some minor HTML issues:

- you have a missing closing `</p>` tag in last paragraph inside section `personal`
- Your main container `container-fluid` closing `</div>` is wrongly placed before closing `</body>` tag:

```html
</div>
</body>
```

Just move it after the closing `</footer>` tag like so:

```html
</footer>
</div>
```